# AngularJS update view after $resource remove()

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I am having trouble updating the view after `$resource remove()`. The element get's removed, but you can only see the change after refreshing the page.

#### Controller

```
this.getData = function() {
  var query = SomeService.query()
  query.$promise.then(function(res) {
    this.data = res; // Gets the data into view
  }.bind(this));
}

this.removeData = function(id) {
  var query = SomeService.remove({data_id: id})
   query.$promise.then(function(res) {
     this.getData() // Makes the request but doesn't update the view
     console.log(this.data) // Returns all the data, even the removed element
   }.bind(this))
}
```

#### Factory

```
.factory('SomeService', ['API_URL', '$resource', function (API_URL, $resource) {
  return $resource(API_URL + '/data', null, {
    create: {method: 'POST'},
    update: {method: 'PUT'},
});
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the culprit.. 
I was using [`ngDialog`](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) and apparently, I was creating 2 different instances of the same controller by assigning the same `controllerAs` to the dialog. So something like:

```
ngDialog.openConfirm({
  controller: 'parentCtrl',
  controllerAs 'vm',
  template: '<span ng-click="vm.removeFeed(id)></span>'
})
```

The fix was to pass the scope object to the dialog:
This is not creating another instance of the controller, but instead, it uses the parent/external one, updating the view on `$resource remove()`.

```
ngDialog.openConfirm({
  scope: $scope,
  template: '<span ng-click="vm.removeFeed(id)></span>'
})
```

However, this seems to be the only fix for now, giving me no choice but to `inject $scope` into the parent controller just for this.